# How to Integrate Magento 2 Store with Jet.com for sales point of view

Tags: magento2, jet.com-apis

I have Magento 2 store and looking jet.com for sales point of view. 
Is this possible ? 
Please suggest me any  possible solution.

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, while I don't believe it violates any guidelines to ask about Magento here, there is a [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) where you may get faster responses.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1. You can directly integrate with CedCommerce's [commercial extension](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/jet-magento-2-integration).
2. You can use a third-party omnichannel integrator that will sync catalog data, inventory and orders to any of a number of marketplaces. While there are a number of these platforms, there aren't many right now that have ready-made integrations with both Jet and Magento. Two that I have found are SellerCloud and ChannelSale. One thing to note is that these typically become the center of your e-commerce operation, with Magento pushed to the fringe, as just another marketplace alongside Jet. That may be good or bad depending on your business model and existing architecture.

Note that I have no first-hand experience with using these integrations or omnichannel platforms like this, so I cannot personally vouch for their quality.